# Prove that set of all permutations on a set is a group under function composition

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image]

I have already shown that function composition is closed on Bij(A) but I am having trouble showing associativity.

The identity element is pretty obvious, and I have some ideas about inverses.

Comment: Not abelian. You'll need to make up counterexamples.

Comment: The composition of functions is *always* associative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that the $\circ$ is associative, we need to show that $$(f \circ g) \circ h=f \circ (g \circ h)$$ for all $f,g,h \in \mathrm{Bij}(A)$.  Equivalently, we need to show that $$((f \circ g) \circ h)(x)=(f \circ (g \circ h))(x)$$ for all $x \in A$ and all $f,g,h \in \mathrm{Bij}(A)$.

By definition of $\circ$:
\begin{align*}
((f \circ g) \circ h)(x) &= (f \circ g)(h(x))=f(g(h(x)) \\ \\
(f \circ (g \circ h))(x) &= f((g \circ h)(x))=f(g(h(x)) \\
\end{align*}
for all $x \in A$ and all $f,g,h \in \mathrm{Bij}(A)$.  So $\circ$ is associative.

(Note, different texts use a different definition of $\circ$.  Here we use $(f \circ g)(x)=f(g(x))$, but sometimes it's defined as $(f \circ g)(x)=g(f(x))$.  The proof is much the same either way.)

Comment: thank you so much! I am used to it being defined as $f(g(x))$ but I can see that it would work either way. I have a feeling this will mean the group is abelian.

Comment: It's not going to be abelian (unless $|A| \leq 2$).

Comment: can you explain why that is?

Comment: If $\{1,2,3\} \subseteq A$, then e.g. the permutations $(12)$ and $(23)$ don't commute.

Comment: beautiful counterexample.

in any case: Identity was as easy as thought, and im pretty sure I have a proof for inverses, I just want to see if it's valid:

Earlier in this assignment we proved that , for functions f: A --> B and g: B --->A if fog = idB and gof = idA then this implies f and g are bijective.

Can I use this result to say this: suppose that for all  $f \in Bij(A)$ there exists a $g$ such that fog = idA = gof. Then by the prior result, $f$ and $g$ are bijective functions. Then $g \in Bij(A)$ by definition and thus each element has an inverse.